# Adding a native DLL path to managed console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, console-application

I have VS2010 solution with 3 projects:

1. A native (C++) DLL
2. A managed (C#) DLL that uses the native DLL
3. A managed (C#) console app that uses the managed DLL

I can set the managed DLL as a Reference to the console app, but I cannot set the native DLL as such a Reference.

To run the console app from within VS2010 without a crash, I must copy the native DLL to the .exe folder.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I add the native DLL to the DLL search path, so that I don't have to do a manual copy?
2. How can I do this so that each configuration (Debug/Release) takes the correct DLL version?

**More Detailed Solution** - due to [Tilak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14224133/135862):
Here are more newbie friendly details based [Tilak's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14224133/135862) below:

1. Add the native DLL as a file (Add existing file...) to the managed console project.
2. In the project properties pane, set "Build Action" to "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".
3. Close the solution or VS2010.
4. Open the managed project `.csproj` file in a text editor and find the `<ItemGroup>` which includes the native DLL name (this was created when we added the file in step 1). We'll make several small changes there:

   1. For the Debug build, instead of `<ItemGroup>` use `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' == 'DEBUG;TRACE' ">` and enter the path to the *Debug* DLL.
   2. Duplicate the entry for the Release build, and instead of `<ItemGroup>` use `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' != 'DEBUG;TRACE' ">` and enter the path to the *Release* DLL.
5. Save the file and reopen VS2010. The dependency should now be in place.

Comment: I would put the native DLL as a File in your managed DLL, and set it's property to "Content" and "Copy to Output directory".

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to do this (maybe rephrase as an answer)? Also, can this method be used to differentiate between the Debug and Release builds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can with copy the files in post build event,

or

Add files as resources.

> How can I do this so that each configuration (Debug/Release) takes the correct DLL version?

You can use `$(ConfigurationName)` in post build event to find out Debug/Release mode. And accordingly you can refer the libraries.

If you are using resource approach, you have to modify the project file to copy based on Debug/Release mode. See details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/msbuild/thread/910add2d-301f-4465-acba-78448ff3068d)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the post-build copy option. I was hoping to avoid it since it puts the responsibility for the copy on the native DLL instead of the dependent project. For every new dependent project I have to change the native DLL build project config.

Comment: Alternatively, how do I add the files as build-dependent resources?

Comment: Add dll to projects as file. Set Build Action to Content. Edit the project file in favorite text editor, define item groups corresponding to debug and release separately. Similar to how different propertygroup are maintained for x86, and x64.

Comment: Excellent, that worked. I'll write it up in a more newbie friendly way.